# GTK: Read-Only Text Entry (Label-Like)?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I need to make a `gtk.Entry` read-only like without using `set_sensitive`, specifically `gtk_widget_set_sensitive` will turn off all events, where as I'm only looking to make the entry clearly read-only, but to continue to receive signals.

It also has to be editable under certain circumstances, so `gtk.Label` is not an option - whereas `gtk.Entry` does not have a `selectable` attribute that can be modified.

The only thing I could think of so far is creating a `gtk.Entry`, waiting for a user to complete input and then replacing it with a `gtk.Label`, this doesn't sound very nice though.

Comment: Is the `editable` property not an option?

Comment: @andlabs `Editable` is quite poorly designed imho - the user can put the cursor on the line and it makes it look editable when it's not.

Answer (score 6):

Set both `editable` and `can_focus` properties to false.

The former ensures that the entry is read-only (while still receiving events such as selection), and the latter avoids the problem mentioned in the comment where the appearance of the cursor makes the entry *appear* editable when it's in fact not.